# How to understand the AIC formula in matlab

Tags: aic

What I'm acquainted to is the AIC formula given in wikipedia, that is

```
AIC=2k-2ln(L)
```

where `k` is the number of parameters and `L` is the maximized likelihood for a given model.

Whereas the AIC given in Matlab (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/aic.html?searchHighlight=bic)) is

```
AIC=N*log(det(1/N*sum_1^N(εε')))+2n_p+N*(n_y*(log(2π)+1))
```

where `N` is the number of values in the estimation data set, `ε` is a n_y by 1 vector of prediction errors, `n_p` is the number of estimated parameters (so it is equal to `k` in the first formulation) and `n_y` the number of model outputs.

Are these two formulae equivalent? If so, how to show the equivalence? One side question is what does `n_y` refer to?

Comment: Matlab's formula is equivalent to the first one as long as the RVs are Gaussian. As for n_y, it refers to the number of outputs, i.e. the number of   variables you are predicting.

Comment: Thanks @RUser4512. How to derive that when the RVs are Gaussian, the first and third term in Matlab's formula is indeed `-2ln(L)`? As for `n_y`, in what circumstances, would we need to predict more than one dependent variable? I thought the dependent variable is always univariate, no?